# Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass

Tags: php, mysql, class

I get an error that says

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::mysql_con() in ........../.../includes/script/import.php on line 68.

Line 68 corresponds to:

```
if(!$ip2c->mysql_con())
```

I do have a `require_once()` statement at the beginning of my script

What could be the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that `$ip2c` is probably not that what you expect it to be.

Comment: How `$ip2c` is created? Please give a code sample

Comment: If your "$ip2c" value is from a query, make sure that a value is indeed returned.

Answer (score 12):

[Dusoft says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568489/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-stdclass/1568503#1568503) it could mean:

- `$ip2c` object does not exist,

  Which is **not** correct because you would get a different error "`Fatal error: Call to a member function mysql_con() on a non-object`"

He also says it could mean:

- `mysql_con` function is not part of the class you are trying to call

  Which is true but not so helpful cos its very difficult to add methods to [`stdClass`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.classes.php).

Additionally it could be to do with serialisation [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340815/undefined-method-stdclassuser-error-when-using-cakephp-auth/2340971#2340971):

- This error is normally thrown when a class instance has been serialised to disk, then re-read/deserialised in another request but the class definition has not been loaded yet, so PHP creates it as an "stdClass" (standard class.)

Or most likely, I think:

- the `$ip2c` variable was not an object and then php silently cast it to become stdClass somewhere in the code above.

  This could happen if you directly assign a property on it.

Like:

```
 $ip2c = null;
 
 //php casts $ip2c to 'stdClass'
 $ip2c->foo = bah;
 
 //Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::mysql_con() in...
 $ip2c->mysql_con();
```

See a [better example here](http://www.eatmybusiness.com/food/2011/08/08/gotcha-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-stdclassrollover-in-on-line/189/).

Comment: This is the only correct answer so far. You don't get error messages about `stdClass` for the reasons stated by other answers.

Comment: I notices that when throwing an exception within a PHP object, my object turned into NULL. I gave up trying to figure out why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

it means that either $ip2c object does not exist or mysql_con function is not part of the class you are trying to call.

Comment: -1 Incorrect. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568489/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-stdclass/6988546#6988546).

Comment: class exists – `stdClass` and it just doesn't contain `mysql_con()` method

Answer (score 0):

I think this happen because "extension=php_mysql.dll" extension isn't loaded in php.ini.
Take a look with

> phpinfo();

Answer (score 0):

It could be incorrect code. I once managed to get that error when I had this line of code:

```
if ($myObj->property_exists('min')){
    // do something
}
```

Which resulted in error line like this:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::property_exists() in myFile.php on line ###

I later fixed the line to:

```
if (property_exists($myObj, 'min')) {
    // do something
}
```

So check for that possibility as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the object does not exist. Please show us the code of how you created it. If you are using it within another class (maybe creating it in the __construct function for example), using:

```
$ip2c = new Class;
```

Won't cut it. Instead do:

```
$this->ip2c = new Class;
```

and then

```
$this->ip2c->mysql_con();
```